# Deploying java app from bitbucket repo to AWS: instance error

Tags: java, git, amazon-web-services, instance, bitbucket

I am getting an error when I try to start my instance in AWS.

So I am deploying a java app from bitbucket repo to AWS. I have created public and private keys and that looks to be set up correctly.

I've created an app in AWS Opsworks and an instance.

When I go start the instance I get the following 'failure log': (please see the link below)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx7TsCKKYTdsSmJFRHl0Y0RjcUU/view?usp=sharing

Any help would be great.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to setup your app in AWS correctly ([Adding Apps](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingapps-creating.html)), because it seems marksite/fizeque is a *private* repo.

See the [section "Git repositories"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingapps-creating.html#d0e29401):

> Private repository–Use the SSH read/write format shown in these examples:
>
> - Github repositories: git@github.com:project/repository.
> - Repositories on a Git server: user@server:project/repository

And (Selecting Git under Source Control):

> ### Repository SSH key
>
> You must specify a deploy SSH key to access private Git repositories. For Git submodules, the specified key must have access to those submodules. For more information, see Using Git Repository SSH Keys.
>
> ### Important
>
> The deploy SSH key cannot require a password; AWS OpsWorks has no way to pass it through.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies if I missed something but it seems that this is failing because of an incorrect password for BitBucket. This is seen in the error here:

*STDERR: fatal: could not read Password for 'https://marksita@bitbucket.org': No such device or address*